# Using floating point raster image for majority filter in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, filter, smoothing

I'm trying to do filter images using Majority filter in ArcGIS. My input images is a float point raster image in .img format. There is an error saying "Invalid parameters". What does it mean?

Comment: Majority statistics apply only to categorical variables which must be represented by integer, not floating point, rasters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on the Comment by @whuber, the **[Majority Filter (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000037000000)** documentation says (with my bolding):

> The input raster to be filtered based on the the majority of
>   contiguous neighboring cells.
>
> **It must be of integer type.**

Answer (score 2):

Majority filter is mostly used as a tool in post processing stage to reduce the salt and pepper effect caused by isolated pixels in a thematic map. So it should be used on categorial raster as a zonal analysis. This means that even for a satellite image with integer DN values, it's not meaningful to use the majority filter.

Comment: This argument is illogical: from the fact that a tool is "mostly" used for some purpose does not mean that its application elsewhere is "not meaningful"! In fact majority filters have many (meaningful) uses besides post-processing. For example, it can be used to implement transitions in cellular automata, to detect blank regions in aerial images, and much more.